# Cannot remove spacing in table cell

Tags: html, css

The space above and below the text "Big" is still there. This is the html. I'm using Chrome:

```html
<table border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-collapse: collapse; padding:0;background-color:red; font-family: calibri light; font-size:70px; vertical-align: top; padding:0px !important;">
      BIG
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left:5px; font-family: calibri; font-size:20px; float: left; ">
      Small text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't want to use `line-height` because then I have to make sure that both the `td` and its contents have the right height. If not, this happens. This is the reason I'm not using divs:

```html
<table>
<tr>
            <td style="line-height:30px;border-collapse: collapse; padding:0;background-color:red; font-family: calibri light; font-size:70px; vertical-align: top; padding:0px !important;">
                text
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Bet you didn't try `line-height` yet ...

Comment: If I use `line-height`, it's possible that the contents of the `td` has a height greater than the actual `td`.

Comment: without `line-height`, if I set the text to 200px, I know that the `td` will be greater than 200px. I dindn't want to worry about setting the height of two different properties.

Comment: There has to be a way of removing that padding without using `line-height`.

Comment: No, because it _isn't_ padding. And regarding your 200px example, line-height does not have to get a value in pixels - it does not even need a unit. Try `line-height: .7` or sth around that, and then see how that does when you modify the font size ...

Comment: You're right, thanks. But what does `line-height` do and why would `line-height: .7` work and not `line-height: .7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a padding thing it's just the font you are using. The space you see it's to handle characters that need more space.

[image]

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Let me try and add a special character.

Comment: That's pretty much the reason. Thanks.